# How to get rid of stacked bar borderlines

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am looking to get rid of two borderlines. The first is the white line between the two stacked bar colors. The second is the black border around the legend color boxes. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
# barplot
colors <- c("grey60", "mediumseagreen")
xFun <- function(x) x/2 + c(0, cumsum(x)[-length(x)])
par(mar=c(1, 15, 9, 5) + 0.1)  # this sets margins to allow long labels
byc <- barplot(as.matrix(counts), horiz=TRUE, col=colors, 
               # assign `byc`
               border=FALSE, las=1, xaxt='n', main="Type of Work Being Done by Country", 
               ylim=range(0, 9), xlim=range(0, 100), 
               width=1)

# labels
labs <- data.frame(x=as.vector(sapply(counts, xFun)),  # apply `xFun` here 
                   y=rep(byc, each=nrow(counts)),  # use `byc` here
                   labels=as.vector(apply(counts, 1:2, paste0, "%")), 
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
labs$labels[labs$labels %in% paste0(0:(5*100)/100, "%")] <- "" #masks labels <8

invisible(sapply(seq(nrow(labs)), function(x)  # `invisible` prevents unneeded console output
  text(x=labs[x, 1:2], labels=labs[x, 3], cex=.9, font=2, col=0)))
# adds % to scale
# legend  (set `xpd=TRUE` to plot beyond margins!)
legend(5, 10.7,  legend=c("Performative Work", "Productive Work"),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
       fill=colors, horiz=TRUE, bty='n', xpd=TRUE, border=FALSE)
```

[image]

### data

```
counts <- structure(list(`South Korea` = c(28, 72), `United States` = c(28, 
72), Germany = c(29, 71), `United Kingdom` = c(30, 70), France = c(31, 
69), Singapore = c(36, 64), Japan = c(37, 63), India = c(43, 
57)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
border=colors
```

wherever it occurs.

[image]